# Deploy using 'Web Publish' - directly from Team Foundation Server 2012 Express (to dedicated server, not Azure)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, windows-server-2008, webdeploy

I need to 'web publish' using 'web deploy' directly to a Windows 2008 R2 server - from TFS 2012 Express (not Azure).

I can deploy to my server fine using 'Web Deploy' from Visual Studio - but how do I configure this to happen automatically through Team Foundation Server 2012 Express?

It is an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, using EF5 Code First Migrations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this string to MSBuild Arguments in build process in TFS build.

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:MSDeployServiceUrl=urlToWebDeloy.com /p:DeployIisAppPath="appurl.com" /p:UserName=username /p:Password=password /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
```